# Error testing coverage , should update recommendation state when data is gotten successfully

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-test, test-coverage

I'm a beginner in flutter and currently learning testing . here i found an error in my project when i run the program.please help me fix it

i got this error

```
 C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe test C:\Expert1\ditonton-master-main\test\presentation\provider\televisi_provider\televisi_detail_notifier_test.dart -p vm --plain-name 'Get Televisi Recommendations should get data from the use case'   
04:51 +169 -4: C:\Expert1\ditonton-master-main\test\presentation\provider\televisi_provider\televisi_detail_notifier_test.dart: Get Televisi Recommendations should update recommendation state when data is gotten successfully [E]
    Actual: [
              Televisi:Televisi(2000-09-09 09:09:09.591918, backdropPath, [1, 2, 3], 1, original_name, overview, 1.0, posterPath, [origin_country, origin_country], name, original_language, 1.0, 1)
            ]

  package:test_api                                                                        expect
  package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 460:16                                      expect
  test\presentation\provider\televisi_provider\televisi_detail_notifier_test.dart 141:11  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

for more detailed code you can see in my repository .here I met 3 errors when testing, and I don't know how to fix it, help me
[https://github.com/rinaoktavira/ditonton-master](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)